The Expectancy Problem of Two Binomial distributions
$X$ and $Y$ are independent of each other and follow a binomial distribution.
Let $X∼B(0.5,7)$ and $Y∼B(0.5,6)$.
Calculate the probability that $X$ is greater than $Y$.
This is a multiple-choice question in China's civil service examination, and the answer is 0.5
enter link description here.
I understand the specific calculation process, but according to the time limit, this question must be answered within 3 minutes, so I would like to know if there is a simpler method and a more general conclusion.

I'll add a formal way of a previous answer.
Let $X := X_1 + B$, where $X_1 \sim B(0.5, 6)$ and $B \sim B(0.5, 1)$ are independent with $Y$ and each other. Then we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(X > Y) &=& \mathbb{P}(X_1>Y)\cdot\mathbb{P}(B=0) + \mathbb{P}(X_1 \ge Y)\cdot\mathbb{P}(B=1)  \\
&=& \frac 12 \left( \mathbb{P}(X_1>Y) + \mathbb{P}(X_1\ge Y)\right) \\
&=& \frac 12 \left( \mathbb{P}(X_1>Y) + \mathbb{P}(X_1 \le Y)\right) \\
&=& \frac 12.
\end{eqnarray}
